# Simulation Nodes: Particles with normal-aligned velocity

Tags: particles, normals, simulation-nodes

This is driving me nuts. I'm trying to generate a particle system with Simulation Nodes in which the particles spray out in the direction of the face normal from where they spawn. I got it to work when the particles spawn only on the first frame, but if I try to do a steady stream of particles spawning on every frame, there's no movement. What am I doing wrong?
[image: Particles spawn at the first frame.]

[image: Particles move out at the normal angle.]

[image: Particles spawn every frame, but all movement is lost.]

Answer (score 1):

The attributes of the geometry entering the simulation zone not from the Simulation Input should also not enter by the Simulation Input.

You have at least these options:

- Use a named attribute:

[image]

- Add the attributes. Since the field from outside the Simulation Zone doesn't exist in the geometry inside, and the field from inside doesn't exists in the geometry outside, adding them doesn't affect the values:

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: See, this is what I love about the Blender community. You're never lost for very long before someone gets you back on track. I can't thank you enough for your help; this is exactly what I needed.